# Find mean, var and sd of the random variable T where T =4S-3H

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, combinations

The random variable $S$ is the score when a fair ordinary dice is rolled once, and the random variable $H$ is the number of heads obtained when two unbiased coins are tossed once. Find the mean, variance and standard deviation of the random variable $T$ where $T=4S-3H$.

This question is a question in my Math A levels probability and statistics in the topic of sum and difference of independent random variables. I understand the concepts $E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$. However I do not know how do do this questions as I am given no numbers. Any tips or advice would be much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: You *are* given numbers: 1-6 for the dice, and p=½ for the coin

Comment: Can you calculate E(S) and E(H) separately?

Comment: and what do I do with that  @Benjamin Wang I am a little confused

Comment: I belive you can calculate it seperatly and the come and add them togetherthe mean is spouse to be 11 var=51.16 and sd=7.15 but I don't know how to get to it. @ Benjamin Wang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$E(T)=a_1E(X_1)+a_2E(X_2)+\ldots+a_nE(x_n)$$

$$\text{Var}(T)=(a_1)^2\text{Var}(X_1)+(a_2)^2\text{Var}(X_2)+\ldots+(a_n)^2\text{Var}(X_n)$$

Treat the $a_i$'s as constants. For example, for $T=4S-3H$, $$E(T)=E(4S)-E(3H)=4E(S)-3E(H)$$

$S$ follows the Bernoulli Distribution because our experiment of rolling a dice *once* has only two outcomes: either you roll a certain number (success) or you don't (failure). For a Bernoulli Distribution,

$$E(S)=p=\frac{1}{6}$$

Can you determine the distribution of $H$ and find $E(H)$ from here?

Comment: I know this rule but dont know what is the a and X. Do you think you can help me.

Comment: Owww i undersat this but from here what do I do? I am stuck and I do self studying so I have no teacher and am very confused.

Comment: Given the type of experiment described above, you can determine the probability distribution of $S$ and $H$. Then you will know how to find $E(S)$ and $E(H)$.

Comment: I am so so sorry I have been looking at this question for too long and now I have baked i don't get what you mean.